# Gambler's ruin with a tie

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is as follows:

> Two people, $A$ and $B$, play a game.  $A$ starts with $6$ dollars and $B$ starts with $4$ dollars. In each round, $A$ wins with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, $B$ wins with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, and they tie with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, in which nothing happens.  If $A$ wins, he gets a dollar from $B$, and if $B$ wins, he gets a dollar from $A$.  Each round is independent.  A player wins if he takes all of the money.  What is the probability that $A$ wins?

This seemed a bit tricky to me at first since $p+q$ is not equal to $1$.  However, since there is a tie, and $A$ and $B$ each win with the same probabilities, I think that $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$.

Plugging our values into the known gambler's ruin formula, we see that the probability that $A$ wins is equal to
$$\frac{i}{N},$$
where $i$ is the amount of money that $A$ starts with, and $N$ is the total.  Thus the answer is simply 
$$\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}.$$
Is this the right logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$? I don't mean the value, I mean the meaning of the quantity.

Comment: @celtschk $p$ is the probability that $A$ wins a round.

Comment: Well, that probability is actually given as $1/3$, so why do you later say it is $1/2$? (I suspect your basic idea is right, but to say for sure, I have to understand what you do.)